# What is the meaning of reference sharing in Serialization? How Enums are Serialized?

Tags: java

I am reading through [ObjectOutputStream Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#defaultWriteObject%28%29) and reading about Serialization and i have some confusions. It states that

> Multiple references to a single object are encoded using a reference
> sharing mechanism so that graphs of objects can be restored to the
> same shape as when the original was written.

What is the meaning of refence sharing mechanism? It also states that

> Enum constants are serialized differently than ordinary serializable
> or externalizable objects. The serialized form of an enum constant
> consists solely of its name; field values of the  constant are not
> transmitted. To serialize an enum constant, ObjectOutputStream writes
> the string returned by the constant's name methodLike other
> serializable or externalizable objects, enum constants can function as
> the targets of back references appearing subsequently in the
> serialization stream.

One reason i can think of is, as Enum fields are constants, so they won't be serialized.
Then how exactly if we have the need to serialize an Enum? Another thing, if the state can't
be serialized, why doesn't the compiler restrict us for serializing an Enum? What is the
meaning, that enum constants can function as the targets  of back references?

Please help in clarifying this doubt. Thanks.

Comment: The spec says: "Enum constants are serialized". How do you conclude from that that they can't be serialized? The meaning of the reference sharing mechanism is explained in the block you quoted. What don't you understand in this quote?

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, what i wanted to say is, if we cant save the state, what's the need to serialize it even. Didn't mean enums can't be serialized will edit my question.

Comment: You can store serialized data on your harddrive, then change the enum & add a new one or re-order them. If you deserialize now it will still work since the name is unique while the ordinal number is not. Any other field data in there should not be touched, you'Ve set it once and it's supposed to be constant so it will be the same when you use the enum with the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Multiple references to a single object are encoded using a reference
>   sharing mechanism so that graphs of objects can be restored to the
>   same shape as when the original was written.

This means that it is possible to serialize a object graph which contains cycles.

In other words if the following graph is to be serialized:

A --> B -- > C --> A (C points back to A).

If you serialize A it will do the following:

1. Serialize A
2. Walk the object tree of A and find B
3. Serialize simple fields of B
4. Walk the object tree of B and find C
5. Serialize simple fields of C
6. Walk the object tree of C and find A
7. send the *pointer* to A down the stream

If it did not do this then serialize A would cause an endless loop.

> Enum constants are serialized differently than ordinary serializable
>   or externalizable objects. The serialized form of an enum constant
>   consists solely of its name; field values of the constant are not
>   transmitted. To serialize an enum constant, ObjectOutputStream writes
>   the string returned by the constant's name method

Because enums are constants the assumption is that they will always have same state wherever they are used so it is not necessary to send down the state of the enum. So when the receiving side receives and enum it simply looks up the object for that enum on its side and returns that as the enum even though the two enums on either side could potentially have a different state.

Comment: Hi @Micheal, thanks for the detailed explanation. It indeed clarifies it. Another small confusion is, enums can functions as targets of back references? Can you clarify this statement.

Comment: When an enum is serialized all that will be sent is the class of the enum and the "string" of the enum. Then the receiving end will get the type of the enum and the string and construct an enum on its side from this. So any state that the custom state the enum has on the send side will not be persisted or received. So if an enum contains a reference to an object, that reference will not be serialized

Comment: Thanks Michael for putting up the explanation in such simple words. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @MichaelWiles you wrote "um it simply looks up the object for that enum on its side and returns that as the enum even though the two enums on either side could potentially have a different state." Will it not cause inconsistency if the sending and receiving states are different?

Comment: @Geek Yes, it will. It assumes that enums of the same name are the same across the two different vm's. The alternative would be to throw an error if it detects they are different - but then it would need some way of checking this and I guess the "writers" decided that doing this wasn't worth it. It has to do with serialization... If you add a field to an enum you don't want all your stored data to now not be deserializable. You'd just want the new field in the enum to be present when you deserialize.

Answer (score 1):

*Multiple references to a single object are encoded using a reference sharing mechanism* means:

If you have an object graph, each object in that graph is only serialized once, regardless to the number of references to it within that graph.  For example, if you have objects A, B, C and D in a graph like this:

[image]

While object D can be reached through the path A -> B -> D and A -> C -> D the object serialization mechanism is smart enough to recognize that it has already serialized object D when it arrives at it through the second path and so doesn't attempt to serialize it again.  I suspect (though have never looked closely enough at it) that the object graph is serialized in reference terms and each object has just its primatives and references stored.  This is important in not only minimizing the size of the serialized object graph but also in handling circular references.

*Enum constants are serialized differently than ordinary serializable or externalizable objects* is because, as you say, Enums are intended to be constants.  While it is possible to break this, so that an enum serialized in one JVM appears differently when deserailized in another JVM this would be the result of adding runtime state to an enum.

Answer (score 0):

First question: it means obvious thing. If object appears several times, it will be serialized once. I.e.:

```
Something s1 = new Something(), s2 = new Something();
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(s1);
list.add(s2);
list.add(s2);
list.add(list);
```

will serialize two objects, sharing reference to `s2` object in two slots of the array list. And even you have circular dependency (list contains reference to itself), it will be processed correctly - object graph is transferred as is.

The enum serialization means another obvious thing. It uses enum names for serialization and de-serialization. This is done in case if you serialize something, send it over wire, and deserialize with different version of the enum class. E.g. When you serialized enum `a` from it:

```
class MyEnum {a,b,c}
```

and then deserialized in another JVM which has enum like this:

```
class MyEnum {aa, a, bb, c, d}
```

you will get the same `a` value, in despite of position (ordinal) of the enum is changed and probably some other features (like a value of hashcode).