# Java serialization with empty and substrings

Tags: java, string, serialization, substring

Had a look at the implementation and haven't been able to think of an explanation to this but maybe someone here will know.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> emptyStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> emptySubStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
        String actuallyEmpty = "";
        String subStringedEmpty = "                                                                 ";
        subStringedEmpty = subStringedEmpty.substring(0, 0);
        emptyStrings.add(actuallyEmpty);
        emptySubStrings.add(subStringedEmpty);
    }
    System.out.println("Substring test");
    // Write to files
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    writeObjectToFile(emptyStrings, "empty.list");
    System.out.println("Time taken to write empty list " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    writeObjectToFile(emptySubStrings, "substring.list");
    System.out.println("Time taken to write substring list " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    //Read from files
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<String> readEmptyString = readObjectFromFile("empty.list");
    System.out.println("Time taken to read empty list " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<String> readEmptySubStrings = readObjectFromFile("substring.list");
    System.out.println("Time taken to read substring list " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
}

private static void writeObjectToFile(Object o, String file) throws Exception {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
    oout.writeObject(o);
    oout.flush();
    oout.close();
}

private static <T> T readObjectFromFile(String file) throws Exception {
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        return (T) ois.readObject();
    } finally {
        ois.close();
    }
}
```

Ultimately these 2 lists contain 20,000 empty strings (one list contains "" empty strings and the other contains empty strings generated by substring(0,0)). But if you check the sizes of the serialized files generated (empty.list and substring.list) you will notice that the empty.list contains substantially more data.

I have noticed that the callers of remote EJB's which un-serialize these substring objects seem to have severe performance issues also.

Comment: You might want to add an actual question somewhere.

Comment: Could be the interned vs. non-interned case. What happens if you call `String#intern()` on your empty substrings?

Comment: Can you double-check that it's empty.list that is bigger?

Comment: Yes the original empty.list is bigger, seems that a serialized reference to the interned object is larger than a new empty string object? Haven't confirmed this however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sizes of the lists are different because java uses a mechanism to store multiples references to the same object, like described:

> References to other objects (except in transient or static fields)
>   cause those objects to be written also. Multiple references to a
>   single object are encoded using a reference sharing mechanism so that
>   graphs of objects can be restored to the same shape as when the
>   original was written.

see [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)

If you look the generated serialized file, you will see:

With 1 String empty inside:

empty.list:

```
ac ed 00 05 73 72 00 13 6a 61 76 61 2e 75 74 69
6c 2e 41 72 72 61 79 4c 69 73 74 78 81 d2 1d 99
c7 61 9d 03 00 01 49 00 04 73 69 7a 65 78 70 00
00 00 01 77 04 00 00 00 01 74 00 00 78
```

The string "" corresponds to the last three bytes (`00 00 78`)

substring.list

```
ac ed 00 05 73 72 00 13 6a 61 76 61 2e 75 74 69
6c 2e 41 72 72 61 79 4c 69 73 74 78 81 d2 1d 99
c7 61 9d 03 00 01 49 00 04 73 69 7a 65 78 70 00
00 00 01 77 04 00 00 00 01 74 00 00 78
```

Note that with one element the resulted file is the same.

But if we want to add more times the same object, we will be faced with other behavior.
Look the respective files with 2 times that string.

empty.list:

```
ac ed 00 05 73 72 00 13 6a 61 76 61 2e 75 74 69
6c 2e 41 72 72 61 79 4c 69 73 74 78 81 d2 1d 99
c7 61 9d 03 00 01 49 00 04 73 69 7a 65 78 70 00
00 00 02 77 04 00 00 00 02 74 00 00 71 00 7e 00
02 78
```

substring.list

```
ac ed 00 05 73 72 00 13 6a 61 76 61 2e 75 74 69
6c 2e 41 72 72 61 79 4c 69 73 74 78 81 d2 1d 99
c7 61 9d 03 00 01 49 00 04 73 69 7a 65 78 70 00
00 00 02 77 04 00 00 00 02 74 00 00 74 00 00 78
```

Note that substring continues "normal", two non related strings with different references. But empty has some extra bytes to handle the issue of same reference.

Six bytes from substring (`00 00 74 00 00 78`) versus eight bytes from emptylist (`00 00 71 00 7e 00 02 78`)

This goes wrong because every repeated string that you add, more extra bytes are added. So when you full your arrayList there will be a lot of extra bytes to make it possible to reconstruct as it's original way.

If you want to know why there is that sharing mechanism, I suggest you to take a look at this question:

[What is the meaning of reference sharing in Serialization? How Enums are Serialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013746/what-is-the-meaning-of-reference-sharing-in-serialization-how-enums-are-seriali)

Comment: Note: This seems to be only the case because empty strings are especially small when serialized. With most objects, reference sharing would cause the file with sharing to be smaller, not the file without sharing.

Answer (score 2):

`empty.list` contains one String object and lots of references to it.

`substring.list` contains 2000 string objects, all of them are equal in content.

You could "fix" this by intern()ing the strings.

```
private void verify(String name, Supplier<String> stringSupplier) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    List<String> inputStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    inputStrings.add(stringSupplier.get());
    inputStrings.add(stringSupplier.get());

    ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream emptyOut = new ObjectOutputStream(boas);
    emptyOut.writeObject(inputStrings);
    emptyOut.flush();

    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(boas.toByteArray()));
    List<String> returnedStrings = (List<String>)ois.readObject();

    if(returnedStrings.get(0) == returnedStrings.get(1)) {
        System.out.println(name + " contains the same object");
    } else {
        System.out.println(name + " contains DIFFERENT objects");
    }
}

@Test
public void test() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    verify("empty string", new Supplier<String>() {
        @Override
        public String get() {
            return "";
        }
    });
    verify("sub string", new Supplier<String>() {
        @Override
        public String get() {
            String data = "  ";
            return data.substring(0, 0);
        }
    });
    verify("intern()ed substring", new Supplier<String>() {
        @Override
        public String get() {
            String data = "  ";
            return data.substring(0, 0).intern();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The question said that **empty.list** contains substantially more data, which is the opposite of what I'd expect too.

Comment: I've noticed that as well. I'd have to look into the serialization/deserialization process.